FATAL ERROR: Unhandled e06d7363h Exception when Importing Surfaces in Civil 3D Design Automation
I am encountering a critical issue while running a script on Civil 3D Design Automation. The error appears during the process of importing surfaces. Below is the detailed log output:
[12/27/2024 00:48:11] Importing Surfaces ...
[12/27/2024 00:48:31] ************************MessageBox****************************
[12/27/2024 00:48:31] AutoCAD Error Aborting
[12/27/2024 00:48:31] FATAL ERROR:  Unhandled e06d7363h Exception at 14671B39h
[12/27/2024 00:48:31] >>>Responding: OK.
[12/27/2024 00:48:31] **************************************************************
[12/27/2024 00:48:32] End AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.

After researching, it seems this error is related to a system-level issue. However, since this is running on Design Automation, I don't have direct access to the underlying system to debug or fix it. I would appreciate any help or pointers to troubleshoot this problem.
